# Выдергивание меню

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, android-layout

Доброго времени суток. У меня такой вопрос, как реализовать вытаскивание(выдергивание меню), как панель уведомлений в андроид.(с авто доводкой при достижении необходимого вытягивания)
для отображения Activity использую Fragment.
и создал LinearLaoyt в который поместил ImageView и Fragment

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это делается через `BottomSheet`.

1. Корневым должен быть в разметке `CoordinatorLayout`
2. Поместите в него разметку вашего меню и пометьте её поведением, минимальной высотой и укажите, что её нельзя полностью убрать через атрибуты:

   ```
   app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"
   app:behavior_peekHeight="100dp"
   app:behavior_hideable="true"
   ```

Comment: Большое спасибо, очень помогло!